# Update query isn't working

Tags: php, mysql, json

```
<?php
session_start();
include('MySQL.php');

$Name = $_SESSION['Name'];
$Check = 'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE FName = "'.$Name.'"';
$Query = mysql_query($Check);

if($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Query))
{
    $Admin = $Row['Admin'];

    if($Admin == 1)
    {
        $ID = $_POST['ID'];
        $Username = $_POST['User'];
        $EMail = $_POST['EMail'];
        $FName = $_POST['FName'];
        $LName = $_POST['LName'];
        $IP = $_POST['IP'];
        $Active = $_POST['Active'];
        $Admin = $_POST['Admin'];

         mysql_query('UPDATE Users SET Username="'.$Username.'", EMail="'.$EMail.'", FName="'.$FName.'", LName="'.$LName.'", IP="'.$IP.'", Active="'.$Active.'", Admin="'.$Admin.'"');
        $Val['Msg'] = 'Those Values Have Been Updated';
    }
    else
    {
        $Val['Re'] = 'Home.php';    
    }
}

echo json_encode($Val);
?>
```

Every time I run the query nothing happens. I know it's not my jQuery so don't worry about that because I triple checked and all my variables are fine. The quotes around my MySQL row title didn't do anything if I took them off or put them on. I've been trying for hours but can't seem to find a fix for this!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: try to echo this statement, `$query = 'UPDATE Users SET Username="'.$Username.'", EMail="'.$EMail.'", FName="'.$FName.'", LName="'.$LName.'", IP="'.$IP.'", Active="'.$Active.'", Admin="'.$Admin.'"'` then `echo $query`. what's the output?

Comment: You've got your quotes backwards. Single quotes are for string literals in SQL.

Comment: To test your query: try setting `User='bob"--'` from the calling Javascript then making your Ajax call (or `User="bob'--"` if you've changed the quotes to single quotes)

Comment: id i tested all my variable but @JW i test the echo and my ID never shoed up hmm im messing around with things. everything but the ID came up.

Comment: OK guys i got it thank you to all of you!

Comment: This code is needs a lesson from [bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's the ID at the end of the query.  You're using quotes around it when it is most likely an integer and shouldn't have quotes.

-- edit:  Seems like the code changed and the WHERE part is no longer there.

Comment: i put the WHERE value i relized that right when i posted this but it didnt change anything

Comment: You can wrap an integer around in quotes, but the query will try to insert it as a string.. Not int

Answer (score 0):

You will have to follow these few steps to debug this.

1. echo the '`UPDATE Users SET Username="'.$Username.'", EMail="'.$EMail.'", FName="'.$FName.'", LName="'.$LName.'", IP="'.$IP.'", Active="'.$Active.'", Admin="'.$Admin.'"'` and see whether the query is correct.
2. Copy the query and run it on PHPMyAdmin & see whether the query gets executed and updates the rows you want.
3. Your query is missing a where clause. So every time you executed the query your whole table will be updated.
4. Try the query below.

`"UPDATE Users SET Username='".$Username."', EMail='".$EMail."', FName='".$FName."', LName='".$LName."', IP='".$IP."', Active='".$Active."', Admin='".$Admin."' "`